# How to build a robust/scalable async await echo server?

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient, tcplistener

Im building a simple TCP client and server as a basis for my networking project. Im planning to use the async await technique for future proof and scaleable server.

If I put wrong ip address, the client cant connect to my server and throw an exception. I can catch the exception using try/catch but is that the recommended way to do?

What do you guys think of the implementation. Any comments for me to improve?

My server

```
    private void startServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (anyIP.IsChecked == true)
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
            Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + IPAddress.Any + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text), Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
            Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + serverIP.Text + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
        }
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            Logger.Info("Listening");
            HandleConnectionAsync(listener, cts.Token);
        }
        //finally
        //{
            //cts.Cancel();
            //listener.Stop();
            //Logger.Info("Stop listening");
        //}

        //cts.Cancel();
    }

    async Task HandleConnectionAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Logger.Info("Accepting client");
            //TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Logger.Info("Client accepted");
            EchoAsync(client, ct);
        }

    }

    async Task EchoAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var buf = new byte[4096];
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
            Logger.Info("Receive " + stream.ToString());
            if (amountRead == 0) break; //end of stream.
            await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, amountRead, ct);
            Logger.Info("Echo to client");
        }
    }

    private void stopServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        listener.Stop();
        Logger.Info("Stop listening");
    }
```

My client

```
    private void connect_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress;
        int port;

        //TODO Check if ip address is valid
        ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text);
        //TODO port range is 0-65000
        port = int.Parse(serverPort.Text);

        StartClient(ipAddress, port);
    }

    private static async void StartClient(IPAddress serverIpAddress, int port)
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        //can i try/catch to catch await exception?
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(serverIpAddress, port);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Info(e);                
        }
        Logger.Info("Connected to server");
        using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Logger.Info("Writing to server");
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                Logger.Info("Reading from server");
                var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer))
                {
                    Logger.Info(dataFromServer);
                }

            }
        }
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
            Logger.Info("Connection closed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Actually it seems like the port is 6666, not 4502?

Comment: you were right. my bad. please excuse. thanks.

Comment: Fixed my typo. I still cant connect on 127.0.0.1(localhost).

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it tells me that the server is not, or no longer, listening. Debugger can give you a clue on which of the 2 is true

Comment: You were right. The server is already closed. What is the recommended way to prevent the server from closing in await keyword? Thanks.

Comment: Client/server works as expected. Any comments on how can I improve?

Comment: Consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I strongly recommend you self-host SignalR instead of using sockets. SignalR is much (much, much, much, much) easier to use correctly.

Comment: @StephenCleary The reason I develop my own tcp communication is because im communicating with an embedded device(which have its own tcp server that I cant tinker). Can I use SignalR for this?

Comment: No. If you have no control over the protocol, and it *has* to be TCP/IP, then you do have to write a socket client.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [.NET TCP/IP FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that I recommend to get some of the basics down.

After just a brief look at your code, these points stood out to me:

1. Both your client and server have times when they're only reading (not writing). This means you're subject to the [half-open scenario](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) (as I describe in my FAQ). A robust server should be writing periodically even if it has nothing to say.
2. Both your client and server have times when they're only writing (not reading). This means that you're [subject to a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html) (as I describe in my FAQ) if the other end is not behaving well (e.g., sending lots of data). However, you can't just read indefinitely or you'll open yourself up to a DoS; so you should decide where your limit is and establish read buffer sizes (and write timeouts) that make sense for your application.
3. Using `ReadLineAsync` leaves you open to a trivial DoS attack, since you can't specify the maximum allowed size of the line.
4. [Your code must be prepared for an exception at any time](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/error-handling.html) (as I describe in my FAQ). Obviously, `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` may throw. What's less obvious is that *any* socket method may throw, including `AcceptTcpClientAsync`.
5. Your code uses a mixture of exception handling types. The `async Task` methods are never awaited, so exceptions there just silently end that method. The `StartClient` method is more problematic, since it is `async void`. You'll need to think through your application needs for error detection and retry strategies, and apply proper handling at every level.

In conclusion, I reiterate my comment: I *strongly* recommend just self-hosting SignalR. Sockets should *only* be used if you have no choice.